# Showing $J(A)=0$, where $A$ is the path algebra of an oriented cycle

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, quiver

Let $Q$ be a cyclic quiver with $n$ vertices and consider the path algebra $A=KQ$. I want to show that the Jacobson radical of $A$ is zero. Since the Jacobson radical is the intersection of all maximal submodules of $A$ I tried to classify them:

For each $1 \leq i \leq n$ we have a maximal submodule of $A$ which is generated by all arrows in $Q$ and all paths of length $0$ except for the path of length $0$ at the $i$-th vertex, so the paths $e_1, \ldots, e _{i-1}, e _{i+1}, \ldots, e_n$. These are maximal submodules in any path algebra. But I was unable to determine any other maximal submodules of $A$. Can someone give me a hint how to find them?

Also is $A$ isomorphic to some other algebraic structure that is easier to work with?

Comment: Think about the case $n=1$. In this case the path algebra is the polynomial ring $K[x]$, and here we know all the simple modules/maximal ideals.

Comment: @AndrewHubery Thanks! For $n=1$ I see how it works by working with the polynomial ring $K[x]$. I however don't see how I can generalize this to other $n$. Could you give me a hint for $n=2$ for me to spot the pattern?

Comment: Take the same vector space at each vertex and all but one map to be the identity.

Comment: @AndrewHubery You are describing a representation of the quiver $Q$, correct? Why can we work with representations of $Q$ instead of working with the path algebra $A$?

Comment: In general, one can show that J(A) has as a basis all the paths i-j such that there is no path j-i

Comment: Because the categories are equivalent. If you prefer, there is a map from the cyclic quiver to $K[x]$ sending all but one arrow to the identity, snd the remaining arrow to $x$.

Comment: @LukasHeger It is not true that we get matrices over the polynomial ring, but there is an embedding of the path algebra into the matrix ring (in fact it is a maximal order in the  matrix ring).